# mongoDB, update an object from a related collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a nested object, the current collection stored an object without an _id for that object. So now I have 1000+ records with nested objects.

I have a master lookup collection, where these nested objects came from.

so the data looks like this:

```
{
    _id:
    name:
    thing: {
        family:
        type:
    }
}
```

The master "Thing" data looks like this:

```
{
    _id:
    family:
    type:
}
```

What I want to do is up data ALL the documents with "thing" data INCLUDIING the _id so my resulting data will look like this:

```
{
    _id:
    name:
    thing: {
        _id: (from the Things collection)
        family:
        type:
    }
}
```

If I were doing this in SQL it would look like this:

```
UPDATE collection
SET 
    thing_id = (
        SELECT _id
        FROM Things
        WHERE family = thing_family
        AND type = thing_type
    )
```

How do I do a similar update in MongoDB??

Comment: never use mongo, SQL is much better

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way do it with the MongoDB update method. Rather you'd either have to do it with an aggregate like @mickl showed, or do it in code.

Here's an example (inefficient) way of doing it in JS:

```
db.MainCollection.find({}).forEach(function(item){
var thing = db.ThingCollection.findOne({"family": item.thing.family});
item.thing._id = thing._id; 

db.MainCollection.save(item) });
```

However, you now have redundant data in two different collections. I would reconsider how you're storing it, so that you don't have to keep both in sync with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like
    db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(item){
        item.thing._id = db.things.findOne({family: item.thing.family, type: item.thing.type})._id
        db.collection.save(item)
   })